# estoy haciendo un programa para encriptar y desencriptar archivos en android, alguien podria ayudarme?

Tags: java, android, md5

puedo encriptar archivos pequeños de cualquier tipo(MP4, MP3, JPG, PDF, DOCX), pero cuando son de gran tamaño me da un error del tipo:

> "Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 150835256 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 121MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 435080136, growth limit 536870912""

el archivo es un video de 500mb pero da error.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void Encriptar_Archivo() throws Exception {

//File archivo = new File(Ruta);
 //Path direccion = Paths.get(("/storage/emulated/0/pelicula.mp4"));
   File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/pelicula.mp4");
   InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
   ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

   int nRead;
   byte[] data = new byte[1999368];

   while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
       buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
   }

   buffer.flush();

   byte[] prueba = buffer.toByteArray();
   byte encriptado[];
   encriptado = Cifrar (prueba);

   decrypt (encriptado); //desencriptas el archivo


 System.out.println(encriptado);


}






 public static byte []  Cifrar(byte[] prueba) throws 
 UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
 NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
 InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {



final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("OOAA2011".getBytes("utf-8"));
final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
    keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
}
final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] result= cipher.doFinal(prueba);

return result;

}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] message) throws Exception {
final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("OOAA2011".getBytes("utf-8"));
final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
    keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
}
final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);


//Path path = Paths.get("/storage/emulated/0/Ejemplo.docx");
// Files.write(path, plainText);
Files.write(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Ejemplo2.mp4").toPath(), plainText);

return plainText;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Y si asignas el tamaño del arreglo de bytes de esta forma:

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/pelicula.mp4");
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

Integer tam = ((Long)is.length()).intValue();
byte[] bytesFile = new byte[tam];
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás intentando leer todo el fichero y mantenerlo en un array para cifrarlo, es normal que un fichero de 500MB te deje sin memoria.

Lo que tienes que hacer es leer cierta cantidad de datos (unos pocos KB) cifrarlos y guardarlos en el archivo destino, e iterar el proceso, algo como lo siguiente (nota: no he probado a compilarlo, es posible que haya alguna errata):

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/pelicula.mp4");
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
CipherOutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(
       new FileOutputStream(fichero), cipher);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int count;
while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```